# How would I join two dataframe based on a partial string match?

Tags: python, pandas, string-matching

I have two dataframes and want to join them based on three fields, `A`, `B`, and `C`. However, `A` and `B` are numeric values and I want to them match exactly in my join/merge but `C` is a string value and I want at least 80% match (similarity), i.e. if `A` and `B` have the same values in both dataframes and the value of `C` in the first dataframe is `abcde` and in the second one is `abcdf` I still want to consider this record in my result. How can I implement this in python?

Answer (score 2):

You can using `fuzzywuzzy`

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz

df1=pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,3,2],'B':[2,2,3],'C':['aad','aac','aad']})

df2=pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,2],'B':[2,2,3],'C':['aad','aab','acd']})

mergedf1=df1.merge(df2,on=['A','B'])

mergedf1['ratio']=[fuzz.ratio(x,y) for x, y in zip(mergedf1['C_x'],mergedf1['C_y'])]
mergedf1#score list here , you can cut the data frame by your own limit 
Out[265]: 
   A  B  C_x  C_y  ratio
0  1  2  aad  aad    100
1  2  3  aad  acd     67
```

Answer (score 0):

I would probably merge first on only A and B, then filter out any rows that have low similarity on the C column, so something like:

```
result = df1.merge(df2, on=['A', 'B'])

# assuming sim is the similarity function that you created to calculate the similarity
idx = result.apply(lambda x: sim(c['C_x', 'C_y']) >= 0.8, axis=1)
result = result[idx]
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: sim is a new function he need to made ?

Comment: @RafaelC I spend  sometime to find the function `sim` ...LOL

Comment: @Wen Oh that's how the OP wants to calculate the similarity, edited, Thanks!